# Template is not getting updated

Tags: html, typo3, templavoila

In my template (fileadmin/templates/index.html) I have inserted the word "test". As you see the view of Templavoilà "test" appears.

[image]

I am trying to update the mapping but when I click on save, clear the cache and reload the frontend, nothing really happens. I can't find the word test on the frontend, not even in the source code. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It's really hard to guess what's wrong... Is `div id="Top_Meta"` mapped to some Data Element already ? (maybe _Metamenu_ ???) in such case it will not apear as Data Element overrides it... insert `Test1`  **BEFORE**  `<div id="Top_menu">...` update the mapping, clear the cache and check again

Answer (score 0):

`TemplaVoila` templates are stored in the database. You have to save inside the mapping wizard again in order to update the copy in the database.
Clearing the cache will have no effect until then.